# How to transpose a matrix in ARM assembly

Tags: arrays, algorithm, assembly, matrix, arm

I'm trying to perform a matrix trasposition of specifically 8 n-bits arrays, each having n bits (around 70,000), to a byte array of n elements.

Context information: The 8 n-bits arrays are RGB data for 8 channels. I need to have one byte representing the nth-bit position of the 8 arrays. This will be running on an ARM Cortex-M3 processor and needs to perform as fast as possible since I'm generating 8 simultaneous signals using the resulting array.

I've come up with a pseudo algorithm (in the link) to do this, but I'm afraid it might be too costly for the processor.

[Pseudo Algorithm](http://i1181.photobucket.com/albums/x437/jerullan/photo_zps84ef1510.png)

I'm looking for the fastest executing code. Size is of secondary importance.
I will appreciate suggestions.

This is what I implemented but the results are not that good.

```
do{
    for(b=0;b<24;b++){ //Optimize to for(b=24;b!=0;b--)
        m = 1 << b;
        *dataBytes = *dataBytes + __ROR((*s0 & m),32+b-0); //strip 0 data       
        *dataBytes = *dataBytes + __ROR((*s1 & m),32+b-1); //strip 1 data
        *dataBytes = *dataBytes + __ROR((*s2 & m),32+b-2); //strip 2 data
        *dataBytes = *dataBytes + __ROR((*s3 & m),32+b-3); //strip 3 data
        *dataBytes = *dataBytes + __ROR((*s4 & m),32+b-4); //strip 4 data
        *dataBytes = *dataBytes + __ROR((*s5 & m),32+b-5); //strip 5 data
        *dataBytes = *dataBytes + __ROR((*s6 & m),32+b-6); //strip 6 data
        *dataBytes = *dataBytes + __ROR((*s7 & m),32+b-7); //strip 7 data
        dataBytes++;
    }       
    s0 += 3;
    s1 += 3;
    s2 += 3;
    s3 += 3;
    s4 += 3;
    s5 += 3;
    s6 += 3;
    s7 += 3;
}while(n--);
```

S0 to 7 are the 8 individual vectors from which the bits are being taken in groups of 24.
N is the number of  groups, m is the mask and b  is the mask position. 
dataBytes is the resulting array.

Comment: Stackover flow is not for algorithm design.  What have you tried so far?  Is there any features of the CPU that you think might be helpful?  Certainly, you have looked at the instruction set before coming here?

Comment: Does your device offer any [bit-band aliased](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/Behcjiic.html) memory? That would certainly be useful. Otherwise, for a bunch of bit manipulation that could be expressed in a couple of dozen lines of C, I wouldn't bother with assembly - given the limited instruction set of the M3 and the fact you simply don't have 'enough' registers available there's not much you can do that a good compiler can't do for less effort.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @artlessnoise I'm not sure what you tried to communicate, but yes I've looked at the instruction set and I have an idea of how to perform the transposition. The intention was in fact getting ideas of people who are more experienced than me to either validate my own or improve them. There seems to be a couple of ways to do the transposition.  Hacker's delight (book) has a shuffling algorithm that can perform it,  but I'm not sure that how to apply it to a 70000x8 matrix. I will post my current code so you can see what I tried to do.

Comment: @Notlikethat The M3 has bit banding regions but I'm not sure how to use them. The reason I'm looking at assembly is because the loop has to iterate over 24000 times. From what I've read is best to avoid nested loops as much as possible in these situations.

Comment: @artlessnoise Thank you for the response below. It turns out that the Cortex-M3 does not support the SIMD instructions.  Only the M4 do. As it turns out,  I ended up using a slight variation of the code posted previously.  Essentially, unrolled the 24 inner loops and performed some memory alignment optimizations.  The performance was acceptable.  I will study your suggestion for further improvements.

Comment: I didn't mean literally *SIMD*; I meant the **idea**.  By using a table look-up you can process several output bytes at a time.  The idea of *SIMD* (single instruction multiple data) applies very well to many video algorithms.  There are some *kernels* (multiplies of a matrix) in reduction/scaling and edge detection that can benefit.  Most [pixel swizzle](http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/texture-tiling-and-swizzling/) can also use *SIMD* concepts (or actual instruction if they exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that are always present when optimizing,

1. Memory bandwidth
2. CPU clocks

### Bandwidth

Your current algorithm is loading a byte at a time.  You may do this more efficiently by loading at least 32bits at a time.  This will optimize the ARM BUS.  For certain the end algorithm will not be BUS bound and if it is, you have optimized for this.

For the different ARM CPUs, there are instructions like `pld`, etc which can try to optimize the BUS by pre-fetching the next data elements in advance.  This may or may not apply to your Cortex-M.  Another technique is to relocate the data to faster memory such as TCM if possible.

### CPU speed

Pixel processing is almost always speed up by [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) type instructions.  The Cortex-M has instructions *labelled* SIMD.  Don't get hung up on the label *SIMD*; use the concept.  If you have loaded multiple bytes into a word, then you can use a table.

```
 const unsigned long bits[16] = {
              0,          1,      0x100,      0x101,
        0x10000,    0x10001,    0x10100,    0x10101,
      0x1000000,  0x1000001,  0x1000100,  0x1000101,
      0x1010000,  0x1010001,  0x1010100,  0x1010101
 }
```

A similar concept is used in many CRC algorithms on the Internet.  Process each nibble (4 bits) and form the next four bytes of output a bit at a time.  Probably there is a multiplication value which can replace the table, but this depends on the speed of you multiple which depends on the type of Cortex-M and/or ARM.

Definitely prototype in 'C' and then convert to assembler or use inline assembler if possible.  If you have many `mov` statements in your algorithm, it is a signal that a compiler could probably allocate the register better than you.  Many sophisticated algorithm use a code generator (scripted in phython, perl, etc) which may unroll whatever optimum loop you end up with and also track registers in a algorithmic way.

**Note:** Double check my table; it is just a first crack and I have not actually coded this particular algorithm.  There maybe more slick ways to process multiple bits at a time, but the idea is probably fruitful.

Comment: Putting the table in TCM is a definite benefit on a Cortex-M, if you go that route.